# Python - Key / Value matching for 1 dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to use a dictionary to store credentials for users. When using the input function to enter a username, this should find and match any entry within the dictionary, and move onto the next section to enter a password, and again match with the corresponding user. However, i can't get this to work.

Please could somebody shed some light on this - any help is appreciated.

Some things i have tried - along with the errors:

**Example 1**

```
users = {"test1":"password1", "test2":"password2", "test3":"password3"}

def test_login_script():
    username = (input("Enter Username: "))
    if username == users.values():
        passwd = (input("Enter Password: "))
        if passwd == users.keys():
            print("\nLogin Successful!")
        else:
            print("\nPassword is incorrect. Please try again.\n")
            test_login_script()
    else:
        print("\nUsername is incorrect or does not exist. Please try again.\n")
        test_login_script()
test_login_script()
```

**No Error - but does not recognise the username.**

Enter Username: test1

Username is incorrect or does not exist. Please try again.

Enter Username:

**Example 2**

```
def test_login_script():
    username = (input("Enter Username: "))
    if username == users:
        passwd = (input("Enter Password: "))
        if passwd == users:
            print("\nLogin Successful!")
        else:
            print("\nPassword is incorrect. Please try again.\n")
            test_login_script()
    else:
        print("\nUsername is incorrect or does not exist. Please try again.\n")
        test_login_script()
test_login_script()
```

**No Error - but does not recognise the username.**

Enter Username: test1

Username is incorrect or does not exist. Please try again.

Enter Username:

**Example 3**

```
def test_login_script():
    username = (input("Enter Username: "))
    if username == users.get():
        passwd = (input("Enter Password: "))
        if passwd == users.get():
            print("\nLogin Successful!")
        else:
            print("\nPassword is incorrect. Please try again.\n")
            test_login_script()
    else:
        print("\nUsername is incorrect or does not exist. Please try again.\n")
        test_login_script()
test_login_script()
```

**Error message - TypeError: get expected at least 1 argument, got 0**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "removed for privacy", line 31, in 
test_login_script()
File "removed for privacy", line 21, in test_login_script
if username == users.get():
TypeError: get expected at least 1 argument, got 0
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: `if username in users`. Since users is a dict, you cannot check for equality, but rather check if username is one of the keys in it.

Comment: You want `username in users` and `passwd = users[username]`  in first case. Or you can use `if users.get(username)`

Answer (score 1):

For a dictionary, you should use in keyword instead of equality operator and to check if the password is correct, do users[username] == passwd.

```
users = {"test1":"password1", "test2":"password2", "test3":"password3"}

def test_login_script():
    username = (input("Enter Username: "))
    if username in users:
        passwd = (input("Enter Password: "))
        if users[username] == passwd:
            print("\nLogin Successful!")
        else:
            print("\nPassword is incorrect. Please try again.\n")
            test_login_script()
    else:
        print("\nUsername is incorrect or does not exist. Please try again.\n")
        test_login_script()
test_login_script()
```